# How to troubleshoot Serverless IAM permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

After setting up Serverless 0.5.6 on OSX 10.11 Node v4.4.5 NPM 3.9.5, I run
`serverless project install serverless-graphql-blog`
and provide IAM credentials for a new profile, I get:

```
    Serverless: Deploying resources to stage "dev" in region "us-west-2" via Cloudformation (~3 minutes)...  
    /Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
            fn = function () { throw arg; };
                               ^
    
    ServerlessError: ServerlessError: The security token included in the request is invalid.
        at new ServerlessError (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Error.js:17:11)
        at ResourcesDeploy. (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/actions/ResourcesDeploy.js:241:25)
        at ResourcesDeploy.tryCatcher (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:502:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:679:18)
        at Async._drainQueue (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
        at Async._drainQueues (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
    macs-MacBook-Pro-4:blog mac$ node -v
```

When I use an existing set of credentials, I get:

```
/Users/mac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

ServerlessError: ServerlessError: User: arn:aws:iam::...:user/...@gmail.com 
is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResources on 
resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:495629083449:stack/serverless-starter-dev-r/*
```

**QUESTION:** How can I troubleshoot what is wrong with the security token?
Is there a verbose option where I can "buy a vowel"?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that *Serveless Framework* is using your *aws cli* configuration. There is a file on your home path (`/home/xxx/.aws/credentials`) that stores yor AWS credentials. Probably your credentials dont have permissions to use *cloud formation*. (Serveless uses *Cloud formation* extensively)
`cloudformation:DescribeStackResources`.

You have to give permission (adding an *asws policy*) to your user to perform action on cloud formation.